# Isolation levels and select for update

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, rdbms

What is the relation between isolation levels of relational databases and `select for update`?

If I use the plain vanilla JDBC connectivity with SQL Server and set isolation level to READ_REPEATABLE and use a simple `select`, would I see inconsistency in repeatable reads or not? Or should I use `select for update` always to avoid inconsistent repeatable reads in transactions? If so, what is the deal with isolation levels, how they would come into play?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't have the `select ...  for update` syntax.  The equivalent in SQL Server is to use the UPDLOCK table hint.

This hint is used when reading a row and *immediately* updating the same row in an atomic transaction.  EG

```
declare @balance = (select balance from account where accountId = @id)
update account set balance = @balance + @amount where accountId = @id
```

At READ COMMITTED, or in any isolation level without a mult-statement transaction, multiple sessions can run the first query, and have lost updates when updating the balance.

Using the REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE isolation level will prevent this update anomaly, but they do it by blocking the first writer if there are any concurrent transactions that have read the row, and if one of the other transactions attempts to update the row, causing a deadlock.

Mostly this behavior is not worth the performance cost and annoyance of handling deadlocks.  So you use 'select for update' aka UPDLOCK to place a U lock on the row while reading and block subsequent readers from acquiring a conflicting lock.

eg

```
declare @balance = (select balance from account with (updlock) where accountId = @id)
update account set balance = @balance + @amount where accountId = @id
```

Comment: Hi David, so should i take UPDLOCK and set isolation level to REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE both together to achieve concurrency here ? Or does simple select gets the lock as well in REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: For a `select for update` scenario you should use a transaction at the default READ COMMITTED isolation level and use UPDLOCK.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "inconsistent repeatable reads" but with the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level in SQL Server, shared locks will be held until the end of the transaction. Only committed data will be returned and other sessions cannot modify the rows read until the transaction is committed (or auto-committed in the case of no explict transaction).

`REPEATABLE READ` does not prevent other sessions from inserting new rows so rerunning the same query in the same transaction may return new rows (phantom reads) that were not returned originally.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) describes this in more detail along with the other transaction isolation levels.

Comment: Hi Dan, should i need to get update lock explicitly (by using 'select for update' aka UPDLOCK) when executing transaction in REPEATABLE READ or simple select would get the shared lock under the hood ?

Comment: @OMERHAYAT, no need for an explict locking hint since the isolation level declaration will take care of holding the needed shared locks automatically.

Comment: so can we safely say here that acquiring locks explicitly in READ_COMMITTED state (by using 'select for update' aka UPDLOCK) is as much consistent as working with simple selects at READ_REPEATABLE isolation level ?

Comment: @OMERHAYAT, with the `UPDLOCK` hint and the `READ COMMITED` level, the reads would be similar to `REPEATABLE READ` except the update locks would block other select queries with the hint. To get the same behavior as `REPEATABLE READ`, you could specify a `HOLDLOCK` hint instead. But there is no reason to use hints when the declared session isolation level suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to intervene with the default behavior using hints or otherwise.
SQL Server guarantees transaction isolation levels per your declared required level.
REPEATABLE READ guarantees that within a transaction, your statements will see a consistent view of the data that was read, but doesn't guarantee there will be no phantom rows. To avoid the latter you will need to use SERIALIZABLE.
The higher the isolation, the higher the concurrency penalty of course.

See the [JDBC Page for isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels) and the [general page for SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) for a somewhat more in-depth discussion.

HTH